# Potentially async function return a promise that immediately resolves?

Tags: javascript, promise

Where `asyncBananaRequest` returns a promise -

```
function potentiallyAsync () {
  if (cachedBanana) {
    return asyncBananaRequest();
  }
  return ??cachedBanana??;
}

potentiallyAsync().then(function(banana){
  //use banana
})
```

I want a banana, I might already have it cached. Is there a way for me to return the cached banana in the potentiallyAsync functionas a promise that immediately resolves with the cached bananas?

I'm currently using the Q lib packaged in Angular, but I'm hoping there's a generic implementation

Comment: See also [JS Promises - if-else flow when only single path is async](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31559165/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While SomeKittens is awesome, his answer uses the [deferred anti pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

I suggest the following:

```
function potentiallyAsync () {
  return (cachedBanana) ? Promise.resolve(cachedBanana) : asyncBananaRequest();
}

potentiallyAsync().then(function(banana){
  //use banana
});
```

In Angular's $q you'd use the exact same thing only with `$q.when(cachedBanana)` instead of the ES6 standards `Promise.resolve`.

This form of chaining and using .resolve (.when in $q) to create new promises are bread and butter of promises. Deferred objects should only be used at absolute endpoints when promisifying callback based APIs.

Comment: Also important to mention - asyncBananaRequest must not throw synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Sure!  Use a pattern along these lines:

```
function bananas($q) {
  var def = $q.defer();

  if (cachedBananas) {
    def.resolve(cachedBananas);
  } else {
    asyncBananas('Monkey.co')
    .success(function(bananas) {
      def.resolve(bananas);
    });
  }

  return def.promise;
}
```

Meanwhile:

```
function monkey(bananas) {
   bananas.then(function(bananas) {
     bananas.eat(); // Yum!
   });
}
```