# Unit-testing, waiting on a promise when $http does NOT get invoked

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, promise

I have a unittest where a service returns a promise.  Sometimes that service might make a $http request, sometimes it won't (It implements a cache of sorts).  In either case, it resolves the promise, but only in $httpBackend.flush() does it actually get around to making the callbacks.  How can I cause the promises that are resolved to actually call the functions in the `.then()` like flush() does.

**This one works just fine**

```
resolved = jasmine.createSpy();
rejected = jasmine.createSpy();
employeeEventService.loadSchedules()
    .then(resolved, rejected);

$httpBackend.flush();  // This causes the promise to resolve/reject

expect(resolved).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(rejected).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**This one doesn't work because I can't call flush()** (since the service never called $http)

```
resolved = jasmine.createSpy();
rejected = jasmine.createSpy();
employeeEventService.loadSchedules()
    .then(resolved, rejected);

//$httpBackend.flush();  // Can't call this because this call is "cached"

expect(resolved).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(rejected).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

---

Service code:

```
if(loaded.startOn <= params.startOn && loaded.endOn >= params.endOn
   && new Date() - lastFetch < 60000) {
     deferred.resolve(loaded.schedules);
} else {
    service.loading +=1;
    config = {params: params, timeout:30*1000};
    $http.get('/api/employee-schedules/', config)
        .then(function(response) {
            ...
            process the json response
            ...
            deferred.resolve(loaded.schedules);
         }, function(reason, status) {
            $log.error("Failed to get schedules", reason, status);
            deferred.reject(reason, status);
         })
         .finally(function() {
              service.loading -=1;
         });
}
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Can we see the service, or at least pseudocode of how the cache is implemented?

Comment: In the secnd case, if it doesn't use `$http` why doesn't it resolve the promises ? Could it be that you first need to call `loadSchedules(); $hhtpBackend.flush();` to populate the cache and then (in the same test) call `loadSchedules()` a second time to get the cached values ?

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your code, not your test. When I cache data from async functions, I return the same promise on subsequent calls. It sounds like you're just returning the data directly.

Comment: It does resolve the promise, but it isn't until `.flush()` that those methods (resolved or reject) get called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All promises, regardless of what pattern they are in, are resolved when you call $scope.$digest();

Comment: And that was the answer!  I found it about the time you posted this by stepping into `.flush()`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a [promise antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) in your service, which is why you're encountering these issues.  Instead, try this pattern:

```
function loadSchedules () {
  return (cachedSchedules) ? $q.when(cachedSchedules) : asyncHTTPStuffs();
}
```

([Thanks to Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22655010/1216976))

This way, you can return a thenable object, regardless of cache status, while not needing to call `$httpBackend.flush()` if you know the data is cached.

Comment: I would agree with you except for the ... part of my then inside the service.  The incoming data has JSON date strings that have to be converted from strings to date objects, and that happens inside the `.then()` function.  I could use `.when` except for that  (and $http transforms are deprecated....)

Comment: @Mark0978 you still don't need to use a deferred, you can use `.then` on the `asyncHTTPStuffs` which would be a lot cleaner and less error prone.

Comment: I don't understand, I am using .then.  After $https resolves, I process the response, store it in the service and resolve the returned promise.  I don't see any way to do it other than how I have.  Or are you saying return he $https promise?  How do I know the call order of .then callbacks?