# How to maintain a promise-like API in this case?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

```
function foo(options) {
  if(!isValid(options)) {
    // I want to return a resolved promise here to permit client code to continue without a failure
  }

  return promisifiedThirdPartyApi(options); // Does not handle an invalid options object successfully
}
```

How can I idiomatically return a resolved promise in the "invalid" case?

Comment: `return Q.defer().resolve().promise()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to return early in deferred promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31933675/1048572) or [JS Promises - if-else flow when only single path is async](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31559165/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Native Promises

Take a look at the native Promise object's static methods [`resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) and [`reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject).

```
function foo(options) {
  if(!isValid(options)) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  return promisifiedThirdPartyApi(options);
}
```

### Angular $q

Use `$q.when` to return a resolved Promise from some non-Promise object:

```
function foo(options) {
  if(!isValid(options)) {
    return $q.when([]);
  }

  return promisifiedThirdPartyApi(options);
}
```

### Q Promises

Use `Q.resolve()` which returns a resolved promise.

```
function foo(options) {
  if(!isValid(options)) {
    return Q.resolve();
  }

  return promisifiedThirdPartyApi(options);
}
```

Comment: No, even with Q you can just `return Q.resolve()`. No need to create a deferred.

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(options) {
  return new Promise(function(accept, reject) {
     if(!isValid(options)) {
         reject();
      }

     promisifiedThirdPartyApi(options).then(function() {
        accept();
     });
   });
}
```

Note that Q might have some shortcuts for this...

Comment: Avoid the [promise constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)