# best practice for Q and promises

Tags: javascript, q

I'm really new to `Q` js library.

I need to write a `prepare` function that may return value momentarily or may need to wait for promise:

```
var prepare = function() {
    var result = {};
    result.aaa = 1;

    if (something) {
        callToFunction().then(function () {
            result.bbb = 2
        })
    }

    if (something2) {
        callToFunction().then(function () {
            result.ccc = 2
        })
    }


    // here I have code to define other properties
    // in sync (like `aaa`) or async (like `bbb`) manner



    return result; //I need to return promise here
}

prepare().then(function(result) {use result....})
```

can someone fix `prepare` function so I can always safely use `prepare().then`

someone may think it is related to [How to maintain a promise-like API in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521737/how-to-maintain-a-promise-like-api-in-this-case)

but it is not.  Function is responsible to define `result` object.

- first:  define `aaa` property
- second: in some cases function will define `bbb` property
- third: define other properties in sync (like `aaa`) or async (like `bbb`) manner

Comment: How is your case different than the linked question? It seems to be just `if (something) return callToFunction().then(function() { …; return result; }); else return Q.resolve(result);`

Comment: hm...  I think I'm starting to understand you.   Then how would you write function if I also have to define ccc asynchronously?  So code will start executing definition of bbb and ccc in parallel.

Comment: or maybe [Javascript - if with asynchronous case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29802311/1048572) is a better duplicate?

Comment: Then how would you write function if I also have to define ccc asynchronously? So code will start executing definitions of bbb and ccc in parallel.

Comment: For that case, use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (or `Q.all`, of course) to gather results from multiple promises, then put them together in your object

Comment: thanks that helps !!!